# How do I set an empty link title in a menu item?

Tags: navigation

I'm using a fontawesome icon in a menu (with the tbmegamenu module) and I want to remove the text. Drupal forces me to enter something, `&nbsp;` doesn't work so as a temporary solution I put at dot `.`
How can I remove the dot without resorting to very dirty CSS tricks?

[image: The house with the dot]

See also the actual HTML at [the website](http://teakmoebel.com/).

[image: Nothing]

Entering an empty string in the menu title would be the cleanest way to get to a solution now.  Maybe it's possible with a hook that lets me put `<none>` in the menu title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Icon API](https://drupal.org/project/icon) and Icon API:Menu submodule, You can just put `<none>` in the text field of the menu item. 
fontawesome icons are available in the menu item properties with this module.

Answer (score 2):

No need to resort to "dirty CSS tricks", you can just use clean CSS:

```
a.class {
  display: inline-block; // Or block if it makes more sense for your layout.
  text-indent: -9999em;
}
```

This is the correct way to handle it, as you can include proper text as your link (e.g. "Home"), so you're not alienating users with screen readers, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes the home icon disappear as well.

Comment: ah, because it's using awesomefont, so the image is part of the text. duh. Can't you use a regular bg image? Or you could have a :after {content: ... position: absolute}

Comment: Right, I guess your icon's in a `<i>`/`<b>` tag or something? General wisdom would be to put that as a background image on the `<a>` itself. You'll either need to use CSS to solve it (absolute position on the `<b>` tag within the `<li>`, for example), or you'll need to change the markup so you can better target the `<a>` and its contents with CSS. There's no half-measure, Drupal won't be able to provide you with a solution unfortunately

Comment: maybe position: absolute on the <i> ?

Comment: @donquixote Yeah that would work, but we're more into the realms of "tricks" with that I think :)

Comment: actually what i tried jus tnow and worked was float:left and text-indent:0 on the <i>, and text-indent:-1000px on the <a>

Comment: You guys might be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12783507/2317532), which aims to replace the `-9999em` hack, which is ugly (and you know it!)  :p

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
<a href="/" class="">
  <i class="icon-home" style="text-indent: -1000px;">
    This is the homepage
  </i>
</a>
```

Comment: This would be the ideal solution, but I imagine there'll be some coding involved to override fontawesome's theme functions

Comment: It's a good solution but that leaves open where to put it. Now it's using TB Mega Menu but the idea is to get rid of that bloat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FontAwesome menu icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome_menu_icons) module in Drupal 8.

After enable it, you get new options in each menu-item edit page:

- A field for setting a fontawesome icon writting the code (fa-user, fa-sign-out,...)
- Another field ("FontAwesome Icon - Appearance") where you can select "Without text" for an empty title.